# The AI in bumping old questions - again and again

Tags: discussion

I came across this: [Comparing two Arrays with excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977174/comparing-two-arrays-with-excel-vba)

It was bumped 43 mins to the main page as active. As the only commentator said:

> I don't know why this questions was bumbed, but it seems like a poor choice. First, it's over four years old, second it is poorly framed and needs clarification, but third, this user hasn't been seen in four years either, so there little chance of getting the needed clarification, let alone it being unlikely that they still need an answer. – RBarryYoung Oct 21 '17 at 20:37

I agree that it shouldn't be bumped, its got 20,000 views now.

Is there something in the AI that keeps popping up this particular Q&A each year? I know its probably due to a lot of Google Search's but the only undeleted answer (which looks good) has no upvotes. So one wonders, is the criteria for choosing questions to be bumped achieving the desired goal?